# How To Call Excel Macro on number of dynamic rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro: in one cell insert information from another cell and then run a macro to convert that sheet to PDF. I have a way to do it with multiple if-then statements but i would like to know if there is a cleaner and easier way. Below is my code. The amount of cells may vary since it based on another macro that drops the information in there. Below is the code.

```
Sub sub1()

Dim ws, ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("sht1")
Set ws1 = Worksheets("sht2")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("sht3")
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ws1
    .Cells.ClearContents
End With

With ws
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:T" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=" & Date
End With

ws.Columns(1).Copy Destination:=ws1.Columns(1)

With ws
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

If ws1.Range("A2").Value <> "" Then

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
ws2.Range("D13").Value = ws1.Range("A2").Value
Call PDFCreate

    Else
End If

If ws1.Range("A3").Value <> "" Then

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
ws2.Range("D13").Value = ws1.Range("A3").Value
Call PDFCreate

    Else
End If

If ws1.Range("A4").Value <> "" Then

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
ws2.Range("D13").Value = ws1.Range("A4").Value
Call PDFCreate

    Else
End If

If ws1.Range("A5").Value <> "" Then

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
ws2.Range("D13").Value = ws1.Range("A5").Value
Call PDFCreate

    Else
End If

If ws1.Range("A6").Value <> "" Then

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
ws2.Range("D13").Value = ws1.Range("A6").Value
Call PDFCreate

    Else
End If

If ws1.Range("A7").Value <> "" Then

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
ws2.Range("D13").Value = ws1.Range("A7").Value
Call PDFCreate

    Else
End If

If ws1.Range("A8").Value <> "" Then

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
ws2.Range("D13").Value = ws1.Range("A8").Value
Call PDFCreate

    Else
End If

If ws1.Range("A9").Value <> "" Then

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
ws2.Range("D13").Value = ws1.Range("A9").Value
Call PDFCreate

    Else
End If

If ws1.Range("A10").Value <> "" Then

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
ws2.Range("D13").Value = ws1.Range("A10").Value
Call PDFCreate

    Else
End If

ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
```

End Sub

Comment: It sounds like you need a loop. Just find the last row on `ws1` and then loop `For Each cell in ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)`.

Comment: @BigBen I'm not familiar with looping. Tried this but it didn't work                         
    For Each cell In ws1.Range("A2:A" & nRows)
        ws2.Range("D13").ClearContents
        ws2.Range("D13").cell.Value
    Next cell

Comment: There are many tutorials on the web on how to loop. Have you tried reading any? It's a great opportunity to pick up a fundamental skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jay please follow @BigBen’s sound advice & do some online tutorials to sharpen up your VBA skills with Loops – and other things.  A Google search of “Excel VBA Loop Tutorial” returns thousands of results.

You say you’re looking for a “cleaner and easier way”.  There are several things you can do to improve the efficacy of your code.  Here’s some observations and suggestions about your code as it currently stands.

Option Explicit.  Get in the habit of adding this to the top of your subs.  It forces you to declare all variables.

“Dim ws, ws1, ws2 as Worksheet” is only declaring ws2 as Worksheet – the first two are being declared as Variant.  Needs to be “Dim ws as Worksheet, ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet”.

I don’t think you really need to find the last row in this case – only the filtered data will be copied to Sheet 2.

You’re heading for a world of pain referring to your Sheet 2 as “ws1” and Sheet3 as “ws2”.  If you must make them variables, and you don’t have to in this case, then do yourself a favour and refer to them more intuitively – Sheet 1 as ws1, Sheet 2 as ws2 etc.  Alternatively, you can simply refer to them as “Sheet1” etc.

You don’t really need a `With…End With` block to do something as simple a clearing a sheet.

`Else` is only used in an `If…End If` block if you intend to put alternative code after it if the test is False.  In your case, no alternative follows its use, so a False return will simply skip to the next line of code.

I’m not sure why you clear the contents of D13 on Sheet 3 every time when you’re always overwriting the data with values from Sheet 2.

If your other sub “PDFCreate” simply exports your Sheet3 as a PDF – you could just write the code in this module.  Just copy the code and overwrite the `Call PDFCreate` line.

Let me know how you go with the code below.  It assumes that your “sht1” is actually Sheet1 (and so on) in the Workbook.

```
Option Explicit    
Sub ConvertToPDF()
Dim c As Range

Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents

With Sheet1
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=" & Date
    .Columns(1).Copy Sheet2.Columns(1)
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
    
'This is the Loop
For Each c In Sheet2.Range("A2:A10")    
        If c.Value <> "" Then
           Sheet3.Range("D13").Value = c.Value
           Call PDFCreate
        End If    
Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this! It worked perfectly and looks much cleaner. It definitely helped me understand how to loop and i'll keep looking into that. This was an extremely helpful comment and I'll keep everything you said in mind going forward for future VBAs